# (Really) An Error in Edwards Proof of the Implicit Mapping Theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, implicit-function-theorem

This one **seems** obvious to me, but I've been wrong enough lately to doubt myself.
I refer to C.H. Edwards, Jr.'s Advanced Calculus of Several Variables, Theorem III-3.4, (the multivariable implicit mapping theorem.) Pages 190 and 191.

> Let the mapping $\mathbf{G}:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$
>   be $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ in a neighborhood of the point $(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$
>   where $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})=\mathbf{0}$. If the partial
>   derivative matrix $\mathit{D}_{2}\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$
>   is non-singular then there exists a neighborhood $\mathit{U}$ of
>   $\mathbf{a}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m}$, a neighborhood $\mathit{W}$ of
>   $(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$ in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, and a $\mathscr{C}^{1}$
>   mapping $\mathbf{h}:\mathit{U}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that
>   $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})$ solves the equation $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}$
>   in $\mathit{W}$.''

In the proof, a mapping $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$
defined by $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}))$
is introduced. The neighborhood $\mathit{V}$ of $(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{0})$
is also defined.

I'm including a link to my interpretation of Figure 3.8 on page 191.
The notation in my diagram is somewhat different from what Edwards
uses. The relevant differences are that I used $\{\mathbf{x}_{\alpha},\mathbf{y}_{\beta}\}=(\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b})$
and $\mathbf{y}(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{x})$. I labled the
axes $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$, which Edwards didn't do.

The proof then ensures the existence of a $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ mapping
$\mathbf{g}:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$, inverse
to $\mathbf{f}:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$. Edwards
then states:

> Since $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}$ if and only
>   if $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}$, it is clear that
>   $\mathbf{g}$ maps the set $\mathit{U}\times\mathbf{0}\subset\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$
>   one-to-one onto the intersection with $\mathit{W}$ of the zero set
>   $G(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}.$

I believe that should actually say "Since $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{0})$
if and only if $\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{0}$,...".

Is that a valid correction?

Notice that $\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{0}$ isn't necessarily in $\mathit{U}$.  In that case

$\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y})=(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{y}))=(\mathbf{0},\mathbf{0})=\mathbf{0}$

may not even be defined.

[image: Depiction of neighborhoods and mappings]

Comment: Yes. ${}{{}}{}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  There is a minor error in the statement of the proof, corrected as suggested.